# Search result page loads blank

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

This is a simple search operation using spring and hibernate. When i enter the search value and hit submit, result page loads with nothing. It doesn't throw any error. Its blank. Please someone point me where i am wrong.

**ProductDAOImpl.java**

```
public List<Product> searchProductByName(String productName) {  
            Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Product.class);  
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("productName", productName+"%"));  
            return criteria.list();  
        }
```

**ProductServiceImpl.java**

```
@Transactional  
    public List<Product> searchProductByName(String productName) {  
        return productDAO.searchProductByName(productName);  
    }
```

**ProductController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="searchproduct.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView searchProduct(@RequestParam String productName) {  
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("searchproduct");  
        List<Product> productResults = productService.searchProductByName(productName);  
        mav.addObject("productResults", productResults);  
        return mav;  
    }
```

**searchform**

```
<form action="searchproduct"    method="post" >  
Product Name: <input type="text" name="productName"/>  
<input type="submit" value="Search" />  
</form>
```

**searchproduct.jsp**

```
<body>  
<c:if test="${!empty productResults}">  
    <table class="productTable"  border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">  
    <tr>  
        <th>Product Name</th>  
        <th>Price</th>  
        <th>Quantity</th>  
            </tr>  
    <c:forEach items="${productResults}" var="product">  
        <tr>  
            <td>${product.productName}</td>  
            <td>${product.price}</td>  
            <td>${product.quantity}</td>  
                    </tr>  
           </c:forEach>  
    </table>  
</c:if>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your form action is **searchproduct** and your controller action is **searchproduct.html**. If I am correct then both action should be same.

And in your result JSP add `<c:choose>` tag instead of `<c:if>` to check if result is empty then show no result found text.

Comment: Yes my silly mistake. I changed controller action also to 'searchproduct' and its working now.